# Sequence of binary trees with different source nodes and with the same Strahler hierarchical order

Tags: graphs-and-networks

I would like to create a picture which contains a sequence of binary trees with the same Strahler hierarchical order (for example equal to 2) e with a sequence of different source nodes "i" (from 1 to 7 for example). Thank you all for the help![image]

Comment: I apologize for my insolence, it was not my intention to offend or benefit so directly. Being a new user, I didn't see how I can appreciate the answers. Regards

Comment: You are not insolent, and your question are interesting. But it's a good habit to try before asking :) And about accepting answer, please see [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
strahler[n_, opts : OptionsPattern[]] :=     
 Graph[Range[2 n], 
   Flatten[{1 <-> 2, Table[{2 i <-> 2 i + 1, 2 i <-> 2 i + 2}, {i, n - 1}]}], 
   VertexCoordinates -> 
      Riffle[Prepend[Table[{(-1)^(i + 1), -(i - 1)}, {i, n - 1}], {-1, 0}], 
           Table[{0, -i}, {i, n}]], opts]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

```
strhlrF =  Block[{i = -1, init = StarGraph[4,
         VertexCoordinates -> {4 -> {0, 0}, 1 -> {0, 1}, 2 -> {-1, 2}, 3 -> {1, 2}}]}, 
  Nest[GraphUnion[#, Graph[UndirectedEdge @@@ (VertexCount[#] + {{0, 2}, {0, 1}})], 
   VertexCoordinates -> 
    (Join[{VertexCount[#]+2 -> {0, j = i--}, VertexCount[#]+1 -> {(-1)^(Abs@j), j + 2}}, 
    Thread[VertexList[#] -> AbsoluteOptions[#, VertexCoordinates][[1, 2]]]])] &, 
  init, # - 2]] &;


Row[Labeled[strhlrF[#], "i=" <> ToString@#, Top] & /@ Range[2, 7], Spacer[5]]
```

[image]

An alternative method that gives the same output:

```
strhlrF2 =  Block[{i = -1,  init = StarGraph[4, 
   VertexCoordinates -> {4 -> {0, 0}, 1 -> {0, 1}, 2 -> {-1, 2},  3 -> {1, 2}}]}, 
Nest[SetProperty[EdgeAdd[#, UndirectedEdge @@@ (VertexCount[#] + {{0, 2}, {0, 1}})], 
   VertexCoordinates -> (Join[{VertexCount[#] + 2 -> {0, j = i--},
        VertexCount[#] + 1 -> {(-1)^(Abs@j), j + 2}}, 
      Thread[VertexList[#] -> AbsoluteOptions[#, VertexCoordinates][[1, 2]]]])] &, 
 init, # - 2]] &;
```

Comment: I was expecting you to answer this question, and once again I'm beaten :) +1

Comment: Thank you @Öskå -- have a feeling that someone will come up with one-liner soon:)

Answer (score 2):

Here is what I propose:

```
flat = Partition[Flatten@#, 3] &;
createMat[mat_, side_] := flat@Insert[mat, side, Length@mat - 1]
mat = {{1, 0, 1}, {0, 1, 0}, {0, 1, 0}}; lt = {1, 1, 0}; rt = {0, 1, 1};
n = 10 - 2;
matTree = 
  FoldList[createMat, mat, flat@Thread[{Array[lt &, Floor[n/2]], Array[rt &, Floor[n/2]]}]];

strahler[mat_] := 
 Module[
   {pos = Position[mat, 1], 
    list = Flatten@Position[Position[mat, 1], {_, #}] & /@ {1, 2, 3}, start, left, right, mid},

  start = UndirectedEdge @@@ Thread[{(First /@ list)[[1 ;; 2]], (First /@ list)[[2 ;;]]}];
  left = UndirectedEdge @@@ 
    Thread[{list[[1]][[2 ;;]], 
            list[[2, 2 ;; ;; 2]][[;; Ceiling[Length[list[[2]]]/2 - 1]]]}];
  right = UndirectedEdge @@@ 
    Thread[{list[[3]][[2 ;;]], 
            list[[2, 3 ;; ;; 2]][[;; Floor[Length[list[[2]]]/2 - 1]]]}];
  mid = UndirectedEdge @@@ 
    DeleteDuplicates[Thread[{list[[2]], RotateLeft@list[[2]]}], # == Reverse@#2 &];

Labeled[Graph[Flatten@{start, left, right, mid}, 
   VertexCoordinates -> 
    Rule @@@ Thread[{Range@Length@pos, ({#2, -#1} & @@@ pos)}]], 
  "i = " <> ToString@Length@list[[2]], Top]]

strahler /@ matTree
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]